# I updated my app to sdk 33 and firebase stopped working and my app does not run (I had sdk 30)

Tags: java, android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl124.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNiFs.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMhGE.png

the application starts and immediately closes, this is the error

```
E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source:78)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:141)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:15)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: www.navacom.com.co.pedbox: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfp.zzyh(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfp.zzuh(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcds.initialize(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccu.<init>(Unknown Source:291)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccu.zzdm(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
            ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that will be help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag/74850656#74850656